# Adding Awareness Api with Unity 3D Android Plugin

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

Currently I am making Location based AR app in Unity with Android Plugin that successfully senses user position and orientation. Now , I need to add Awareness APi in that plugin , so I added the following code in the Create method of my MainActivity.java.

```
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .addApi(Awareness.API)
            .build();
    mApiClient.connect();
```

However , on starting the apk in android device , the app  says it stops responding. Commenting the above code makes the app work, creating only the Builder instance also makes the app work.

The above code along with other awareness functionality is working perfectly when creating a separate android app in android studio.

I tried adding google play service jar file as well as src file for the Contextmanager package , which contains Awareness method , but still same message appears.

Kindly let me know how to make this work in unity App?

Comment: Since you claim that `mApiClient.connect();` causes the problem, why not check if `mApiClient` is null before calling `mApiClient.connect();`. Put that code  in a try catch block then display the message with Log.v... Maybe there is a hidden problem you will discover...

Comment: Hi , No actually issue is causing from addApi line itself, and also putting this in a try catch block doesn't keep the app from stopping responding. I am not sure how to show error message in unity 3d view if android plugin throws exception. The plugin itself it working fine if the apk is generated from android studio as an application , instead of unity 3d

Comment: I know that the code is working in Android Studio. This is Unity plugin so what I am saying still applies. It doesn't matter if the try catch does not keep the app from stopping responding. All I want to know is if it throws any exception.  You can use Android Monitor from Android Studio to see the Log. Just select your device then run your app from your phone. The log will show. Are you extending `UnityPlayerActivity` activity in your MainActivity class?

Comment: Yup I am extending UnityPlayerActivity, for the Unity Plugin. The working apk was being extended from AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Did you try the exception thing I said? What was the error? I want to help but want to make sure that my answer is actually problem

Comment: Hey Finally got it to working. Actually it was not finding the Awareness library. So after manually adding the contextmanager jar file in unity folder , it worked. However , now the unity app is unable to determine the current activity, at it fetches empty string from the method that is supposed to return the current activity.

Comment: You really didn't answer my question multiple times so  don't think I can help you until I know the result of that question. Happy coding!

Comment: Now everything is working fine. Actually that was the exception. It was unable to detect the api.